# Can you serialize the same object in multiple Threads?

Tags: c#

If I have a few threads running concurrently and they serialize the same object at the same time but to different streams will it cause a problem?

Comment: Question is far too broad and does not provide a specific behaviour or problem. Try to provide at least some sample code as to what you're asking.

Comment: Is the object being modified by multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: The object is not being changed.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the serializer your are using but most of them are simply calling the getters of the object properties. So as long as the getters of your object properties are thread-safe, serializing the same object instance from multiple threads should be thread safe.